# why doesnt eclipse recognize java 17 maven projects?

Tags: eclipse, java-17

Im using eclipse 2022-09. I have java 17.0.5 downloaded and added in eclipse installed JRE configuration and it is checked as the default compiler.

[image]

I dont know how to explain the issue clearly. When I import a maven project that uses java 17 (pom.xml has property <java.version>17</java.version>) it seems to not recognize it as a java project. Within the same workspace I can import a java 1.8 project and it will add a Java Resources "folder looking thing" when you expand it lists all the java packages.

[image]

Java Resources doesn't get added for java 17 projects:

[image]

In java 1.8 projects it correctly highlights syntax for java code. In java 1.8 projects I can highlight a class name and hit f3 to jump to the class definition. For java 17 projects when I hit F3 it throws up an error window:
[image: error dialog]

Eclipse apparently does not recognize the ooey gooey javaey goodness of any of my java 17 projects. Is there something else I need to do to get java 17 projects imported correctly? I need 1.8 and 17 to load in same workspace if possible - willing to have different workspaces if that is the only option though.

Answer (score 0):

ugh so answer is eclipse maven plugin is using my installed version of maven which uses JAVA_HOME - this was set to java 14 for other reasons. The solution was to set maven java to use workspace default and set workspace default to java 17. Shuffling different versions of java is very painful as I have to run apps with 1.8, 14, 17 and different versions of maven are needed for 1.8 vs 17. I guess this means we cant have java 1.8 and 17 versions in the same workspace as I dont see any option to set maven compiler version per project in eclipse and its not respecting the java.version set in the pom.

[image]